# How to get object array values to other array values within the object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, area

I have an object with areas for a map. Because I use the homepage areas for all other areas too.I want to use something to refer the homepage areas to all other areas thus the code is more readable and shorter.
How can I use the object array homepage for edit ? So the code get's shorter. Something like this _images.edit.areas=_images.homepage.areas ? Or should I define homepage in a separate object?

```
var _images = {
         homepage: {   
            path: 'homepage.jpg',    
            areas: [{      
                coords: '45,143,106,158',   
                text: 'edit',        
                goto: 'edit'       
              }, {
                coords: '45,164,149,180',
                text: 'config',
                goto: 'config' 
              }, {
                coords: '45,181,108,196',
                text: 'setfree',
                goto: 'setfree'
              }]
          },
         edit:{
            path: 'edit.jpg',
            areas: [{     
                coords: '18,131,113,140',  
                text: 'homepage',
                goto: 'homepage'
              }, {
                coords: '45,164,149,180',
                text: 'config',
                goto: 'config'
              }, {
                coords: '45,181,108,196',
                text: 'setfree',
                goto: 'setfree'
              },{ //above everything is like in hompage, below are news areas
             coords: '638,467,652,478',
             text: 'contract',     
             goto: 'contract'
             }]
             },
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. With the assignment

```
_images.edit.areas = _images.homepage.areas;
```

you make a reference from hompage to edit. Every change in eihter homepage part or at edit part is available at both object, because they are linked together.

If you want that, then it's fine - but if not, then I suggest to use two independent objects.